# Set overflow menu text color

Tags: android

In my main theme, I include this:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/ListPopupWindow</item>
```

in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="ListPopupWindow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark</item>    
</style>
```

where `bright_foreground_holo_dark` is a light gray (`#fff3f3f3`). Yet the text appears as black. The background is a dark gray, as it should be in the dark holo theme.

These definitions are in the android [styles.xml source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml).

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/spinner_dropdown_background</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-10dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>        
</style>

<style name="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?textAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">?textColorHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?textColorHint</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">?textColorLink</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have the same problem and tried a lot of different approaches. It almost looks like there is no hook for that/Android ignores any of the available candidates.

Comment: got stuck at the same thing. did you figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Just in case someone is looking for help,

To change the font color of overflow menu item, your main theme should include

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
```

and in `style.xml`

```
<style name="PopupMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

choose any parent `TextAppearance.Medium` /`TextAppearance.Small` depending upon needs.

Comment: Wish I'd seen this first - after a lot of trial & error I came to the same conclusion. There are a lot of duplicate questions with hacky answers, but this should be the accepted solution.